How to merge structure through LAMMPS
I tried to put an organic molecule in-between the bilayer graphene within the Al2O3/Bilayer Graphene/Al2O3 structure. This is my input file.
units metal
dimension 3
boundary p p p
atom_style charge
neighbor 0.3 bin
neigh_modify delay 0 every 1 check yes
read_data algral.lmp extra/atom/types 5 extra/bond/types 5 extra/angle/types 7 extra/dihedral/types 6 extra/improper/types 1&
                     extra/bond/per/atom 100 extra/angle/per/atom 100 extra/dihedral/per/atom 100 extra/improper/per/atom 100
read_data data.lmp add append offset 5 0 0 0 0 shift -7.6358 -8.1025 595.83905
mass 5 12.01115
mass 6 28.086
mass 7 15.9994
mass 8 12.01115
mass 9 1.00797
write_data combination.data

This is the organic molecule file.
LAMMPS data file via write_data, version 17 Apr 2024, timestep = 1000000, units = real

22 atoms
5 atom types
22 bonds
5 bond types
35 angles
7 angle types
32 dihedrals
6 dihedral types
1 impropers
1 improper types

-1.351409985 38.648590015 xlo xhi
0.507632222 40.507632222 ylo yhi
-0.809129944 39.190870056 zlo zhi

Masses

1 12.01115
2 28.086
3 15.9994
4 12.01115
5 1.00797

Pair Coeffs # lj/cut/coul/long

1 0.16 3.47451
2 0.0400184 4.05343
3 0.228 2.85978
4 0.039 3.87541
5 0.038 2.44997

Bond Coeffs # harmonic

1 322.716 1.526
2 238 1.809
3 392.8 1.665
4 273.2 1.425
5 340.618 1.105

Angle Coeffs # harmonic

1 46.6 110.5
2 0 0
3 44.1 117.3
4 42.3 113.1
5 56.4 124.1
6 39.5 106.4
7 57 109.5

Dihedral Coeffs # harmonic

1 1.4225 1 3
2 1.4225 1 3
3 0 1 0
4 0 1 0
5 0.1 1 3
6 0.7 1 3

Improper Coeffs # cvff

1 0 0 0

Atoms # full

14 1 5 0.1 18.4862765156762 16.726520910450933 18.284858301225892 0 0 0
......
......
......
3 -0.0031827955709473788 -0.003964910102101291 0.004825837140135066

Bonds

1 5 11 12
2 5 11 13
3 5 11 14
4 4 8 11
5 1 4 5
6 2 4 7
7 1 1 2
8 1 1 6
9 1 5 6
10 1 2 3
11 4 10 19
12 5 19 20
13 5 19 21
14 5 19 22
15 3 7 8
16 3 7 9
17 3 7 10
18 5 15 16
19 5 15 17
20 5 15 18
21 4 9 15
22 1 3 4

Angles

1 6 12 11 13
2 6 12 11 14
3 7 8 11 12
4 6 13 11 14
5 7 8 11 13
6 7 8 11 14
7 5 7 8 11
8 1 3 4 5
9 2 3 4 7
10 2 5 4 7
11 1 2 1 6
12 1 5 6 1
13 1 4 5 6
14 1 3 2 1
15 5 7 10 19
16 6 20 19 21
17 6 20 19 22
18 7 10 19 20
19 6 21 19 22
20 7 10 19 21
21 7 10 19 22
22 3 4 7 8
23 3 4 7 9
24 3 4 7 10
25 4 8 7 9
26 4 8 7 10
27 4 9 7 10
28 6 16 15 17
29 6 16 15 18
30 7 9 15 16
31 6 17 15 18
32 7 9 15 17
33 7 9 15 18
34 5 7 9 15
35 1 2 3 4

Dihedrals

1 6 7 8 11 12
2 6 7 8 11 13
3 6 7 8 11 14
4 1 3 4 5 6
5 3 3 4 7 8
6 3 3 4 7 9
7 3 3 4 7 10
8 3 5 4 7 8
9 3 5 4 7 9
10 3 5 4 7 10
11 1 6 1 2 3
12 1 2 1 6 5
13 2 6 5 4 7
14 1 4 5 6 1
15 1 1 2 3 4
16 6 7 10 19 20
17 6 7 10 19 21
18 6 7 10 19 22
19 4 4 7 8 11
20 5 9 7 8 11
21 5 10 7 8 11
22 4 4 7 9 15
23 5 8 7 9 15
24 5 10 7 9 15
25 4 4 7 10 19
26 5 8 7 10 19
27 5 9 7 10 19
28 6 7 9 15 16
29 6 7 9 15 17
30 6 7 9 15 18
31 1 2 3 4 5
32 2 2 3 4 7

Impropers

1 1 3 4 5 7

This is the Al2O3/Bilayer Graphene/Al2O3 file.
 # LAMMPS data file written by OVITO Basic 3.10.4
 
 85080 atoms
  4 atom types
 
 0.0 24.7284 xlo xhi
 0.0 23.795 ylo yhi
 0.0 1231.6781 zlo zhi
 
 Masses
 
 1 15.9994  # O
 2 26.981538  # Al
  3 12.0107  # C 
  4 12.0107  # C 
 
 Atoms  # charge
 
           1           1   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        1.4562539999999999        607.09167213379999
......
......
......
       85079           4   0.0000000000000000        19.233180766800000        21.415500000000002        619.59689988310004     
       85080           4   0.0000000000000000        23.354564281199998        19.036000000000001        619.59689988310004

After I launched the calculation, I obtain the following error message.
LAMMPS (17 Apr 2024)
ERROR: No bonds allowed with atom style charge (../read_data.cpp:221)
Last command: read_data algral.lmp extra/atom/types 5 extra/bond/types 5 extra/angle/types 7 extra/dihedral/types 6 extra/improper/types 1                     extra/bond/per/atom 100 extra/angle/per/atom 100 extra/dihedral/per/atom 100 extra/improper/per/atom 100
srun: error: b09r4n19: tasks 0-31: Exited with exit code 1
srun: launch/slurm: _step_signal: Terminating StepId=17337968.0

Would anyone please tell me how to correct my input file to put the organic molecule into between the bilayer graphene structure?
Thank you in advance.
